# Summation of a series help: $\sum \frac{n-1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Can someone teach me how to solve the following series. I have no idea how to deal with factorial.

$$\sum_2^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}$$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac 1{n!} = \mathrm{e}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521861/proof-by-induction-that-sum-i-1n-fracii1-1-frac1n1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compute this using a few tricks:  First, since the series converges by the Ratio Test, you can split it up as the difference of two sums (each of these sums also will converge by the Ratio Test).  Then, you can re-index one of the sums to make all of the terms in the second sum line up nicely with the terms in the first, so that they all cancel (this is the idea behind telescoping sums, but is able to be written a bit more explicitly since all series involved converge), and using all of these yields a very nice result.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!} &= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\\
&= \frac{1}{1!} = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: I feel this is an overly complicated way to say it is telescopic...(and consider that the nth term goes to $0$)

Comment: This may be a complicated way to say it is telescoping, but the reason I did it this way was to demonstrate a few of the other techniques one does not often see used with telescoping series.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac{n-1}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!}$$

Answer (score 2):

## $$\sum_2^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}$$

## $$=\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}$$

As you plug in values of $n$, terms start cancelling out and the required summation is hence $=1$

Comment: How did you get the latex so large?

Comment: @NotNotLogical, by putting a '$=$' in the next line. Click the edit button and see how it works... I also discovered it accidentally.

Comment: @NotNotLogical: It works because putting one or more dashes or equals signs on the next line is one of the ways to format a heading in Markdown. Prefixing the line with a `#` would work just as well.

Comment: You can find more about headings in Markdown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers).

Comment: $\verb={\Huge\sum}=$ yields ${\Huge\sum}$

$\verb={\huge\sum}=$ yields ${\huge\sum}$

$\verb={\LARGE\sum}=$ yields ${\LARGE\sum}$

$\verb={\Large\sum}=$ yields ${\Large\sum}$

$\verb={\large\sum}=$ yields ${\large\sum}$

$\verb={\small\sum}=$ yields ${\small\sum}$

$\verb={\tiny\sum}=$ yields ${\tiny\sum}$

Comment: **Why** did you try to get the LaTeX so large?

Comment: @Did why do you think he tried? If you read the comments, you'll understand that he didn't.

Comment: @Did, I *discovered it accidentally*, while typing out the answer.

Comment: OK. And why do you actually use this discovery?

Comment: Because I find it interesting... Any problems?