# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, factorial, telescopic-series

Can someone give an explanation using the definition of convergence in partial sum to show how the above infinite sum converges to 1?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to $\sum \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$?

Comment: See also [Summation of a series help: $\sum \frac{n-1}{n!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/764065) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/764065).

Answer (score 7):

This is what's known as a telescoping series. Notice how
$$\frac{n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
Therefore, since all terms except the first and last cancel out,
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{n}{(n+1)!} = $$$$\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right) = $$
$$\frac{1}{1!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$
Taking the limit as $k$ goes to $\infty$, we see that the sum converges to $1$.

Comment: " using the definition of a convergence ". I think he needs a proof using the definition of convergence

Comment: The way I learned it, a series converges (by definition) to $a$ if $a$ is the limit of its partial sums. So, finding an explicit formula for the partial sums and taking the limit seemed to be the sort of thing OP was looking for.

Comment: this is what I was looking for.  I didn't realize you could make it telescoping.  Thanks!

(Kira you are correct, that was a typo)

Answer (score 5):

The answer by **florence** is nice and probably the best approach. Here's another, just for fun. We have
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
This is a power series which is absolutely convergent everywhere, so we're free to manipulate at will.

First subtract $1$ from both sides:
$$e^x - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Divide both sides by $x$ to obtain
$$\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$
Differentiate both sides to obtain
$$\frac{xe^x - (e^x - 1)}{x^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}$$
(We can include or exclude the $n=0$ term as it is zero.)

Finally, evaluate at $x=1$:
$$1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$