# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}= 1-\frac1{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Required to prove: $1-\frac1{(k+2)!}$

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}&=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i}{(i+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\\
&= 1-\frac1{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\tag{induction hyp.}\\[1em]
\end{align*}$$

At my inductive solution i got stuck at the above section where i add the $k+1$ value to the inductive solution. Please help.

Comment: Part of your problem was that you had an error (which may have been a typo) in your partial calculation; I corrected it when I improved the formatting, so you might want to compare what’s there now with what you had before.

Comment: This can also be proven by power series manipulation (generating functions).  I posted the details as an answer to the question which this is a duplicate of: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1858706/350214

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}$$
we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}=\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{i}{(i+1)!}$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad=\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}+\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\frac{k+1+(k+2)!-(k+2)}{(k+2)!}$$
$$\quad=\frac{(k+2)!-1}{(k+2)!}$$
$$\quad=1-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}$$

Comment: induction hyp....